# discord.py change prefix command indention error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

> I use python 3.8.7

I am currently work on a discord bot and I was try to make command to change the bot prefix but i get this error:

```
File "d:/Documents/Discord/Bot/Giveaway Bot/bot.py", line 53
    prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] = '>'
                                        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I tried many things but it doesn't seem to work. The error is not explaining very well. It doesn't seem like a indention error. It something else.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import json

def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]




client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= get_prefix)


@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready')




@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
     with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] = '>'


    with open('prefix.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)


@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('prefix.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)



@client.command()
async def changeprefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix


    with open('prefix.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4) 

    await ctx.send(f'The prefix was changed to {prefix}', delete_after=30.0)
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
     with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] = '>'


    with open('prefix.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

`with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:` is indented by 1 space.

Whenever you see an `IndentationError`, check the number of spaces in front of every line. I also recommend an editor with indentation lines like Kate.